# single number problem of Leetcode about the use of pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Why doesn't my `singleNumber` function work normally? If I use an array index in the `for` loop instead of a pointer, it works.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int singleNumber(int* nums, int numsSize);

int main(void){
    int array[] = {4,1,2,1,2};
    int single;
    single = singleNumber(array, 5);
    printf("%d\n", single);
    
    return 0;
}

int singleNumber(int* nums, int numsSize){
    int n = *nums;
    for(nums = nums + 1; nums < (nums + numsSize); nums++)
        n = n ^ (*nums);
    return n;
}

/*************************************
the following version can work normally

int singleNumber(int* nums, int numsSize){
    int n = nums[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < numsSize; i++)
        n = n ^ nums[i];
    return n;
}
***************************************/
```

Comment: Think about `nums < (nums + numsSize)`.

Comment: You could define `int *end = nums + numsSize;` before the `for` loop, and then test `nums < end;` in the `for` loop control expression.

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop you always increase the pointer `nums` and the condition is, "Is `nums` still less than `(nums + numsSize)`?"  So, whenever your `nums` is increased, the condition becomes bigger also and your loop will still looping until you reach a memory address which you can't dereference or it's not valid.  Basically,
to avoid this problem I advise you to define a pointer variable which holds the end of the list:

```c
int *last = nums + numsSize;
for (nums = nums + 1 ; nums < last ; 
nums++)
```